# Why do I keep getting a connection lost error in Nicehash Bitcoin mining

Tags: mining-pools, algorithms, nicehash

The algorithm I'm using is daggerhashimoto. At first I thought this was because of my country blocking Bitcoin mining or something, but it doesn't work even if I'm using a VPN (vpnbook.com/freevpn). Here's how the excavator console looks like. As you can see, the hashing speed stays at 0 H/s, and it's not connecting at all:

[image: excavator console]

And I did leave my laptop mining overnight, but the speed never passed 0 H/s, so this has nothing to do with me not waiting long enough for it to connect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I reinstalled Nicehash, this solved the problem :)

Comment: Which version did you reinstalled?